# GSA: Is it possible to track search results that don't results in click-thrus?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is it possible to track search results that don't results in click-thrus - situations when returned results are not very helpful/interesting and none of them is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes.  Out of the box, no.

The GSA does have a click tracking feedback loop but the data that you are asking for is not collected.  It collects searches, clicks but you can't get a report on "failed searches".  In order to do this, you would have add a custom ct type, export the data and run your own reports.  Or...use your favorite analytics tool to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is something automatically done by GSA. The component is called ASR. Advance Search Reporting. If enabled, it will monitor the user activities and rank the results based on usage. It basically works like a metric system.

You can read more about it here https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/advanced_search_reporting.html